# В чем разница между компаратором и предикатом?

Tags: c++, c, терминология

В интернете я нашел такие определения

> Компаратор — это функция, которая используется для сравнения элементов.

> Предикат — это функция, возвращающая логическое значение.

Судя из определений, предикатом является любая булевая функция, а компаратор это некое подмножество предиката, которое занимается именно сравнением (что логично, так как англ. "compare" означает "сравнивать").

Но я не понимаю, почему, например, в [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) используют `Compare`, а в [std::count_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) используют `Predicate`, хотя и там и там идет сравнение элементов.

---

И собственно вопрос: **когда и что правильнее называть компаратором, а когда и что предикатом?**

Answer (score 2):

Компаратору нужно **отношение порядка** (strict weak ordering) (например, возможность сравнения "меньше или равно"). Это как раз то, что требуется в сортировке. Заметьте, что не для всех объектов возможно установление порядка (в т.ч. транзитивное отношение).

`count_if` может использовать любой предикат, например, на вхождение в некое множество, на равенство (equivalence relationship), или то же самое сравнение порядка с неким значением с помощью компаратора

Comment: Строго говоря бывают компараторы, которые не определяют отношение порядка. Например для "камень-ножницы-бумага" компаратор есть, а порядка нет. Требования возникают, когда вы передаёте компаратор в сортировку, но на сортировке свет клином не сошелся.

Answer (score 2):

Предикат - функция возвращающая булево значение.

Компаратор - функция сравнивающая два значения и возвращающая что-то про их порядок.

Компаратор может не быть предикатом. Например, [qsort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) использует компаратор `int (*comp)(const void*, const void*)`. Он возвращает целые числа, которые описывают порядок аргументов. Если число отрицательное, первый аргумент меньше второго. Если положительное, первый аргумент больше второго. Если ноль, аргументы равны. `comp` - компаратор (он сравнивает), но не предикат (значения не булевы).

Компаратор может быть предикатом. Например, [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) может использовать компаратор `bool cmp(const Type1& a, const Type2& b)`, который и предикат.

Предикат может не быть компаратором. Например, любая булева функция с одним аргументом точно предикат и точно не компаратор.

И конечно бывают не предикаты не компрараторы. пример приводить не буду.

Итого:

1. никакой связи между предикатами и компараторами нет;
2. часто встречаются компараторы-предикаты.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Вы поняли правильно, компараторы - подмножество предикатов.

> а в std::count_if используют Predicate, хотя и там и там идет сравнение элементов.

Сравнение чего с чем? Там у предиката один аргумент, а компаратор должен сравнивать два.